# display only network interface and ip address using ifconfig and awk

Tags: awk, grep, ifconfig

I'm not interested in all the information of ifconfig output, I just want to know the network interface with its respective ip address.

I can get the network interface from ifconfig using the command:

```
ifconfig |grep "      L" |  awk '{ print $1}'
```

```
eth0
lo
tun0
```

and the ip address of each interface with the command

```
ifconfig |grep "inet:" | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'
```

```
192.168.0.10
127.0.0.1
10.5.0.13
```

How can display both data together, network interface and ip addres with just one command or script?

```
eth0 - 192.168.0.10
lo - 127.0.0.1
tun0 - 10.5.0.13
```

Comment: How about using "ip addr show" instead of ifconfig?

Comment: It is the same, network interface and ip address are displayed in different lines

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `ip route show` instead to get the information you want. Filter with this command for example:

```
ip r show|grep " src "|cut -d " " -f 3,12
```

outputs something like:

```
eth0 192.168.1.114
```